# pip install ecapture Failed to build scikit-image

Tags: python, pip, scikit-image

Hi i want to install pip install ecapture, the install fails.
i have scratched my head and i cant see the angle around it issue, i wanted to see if there was anyone ells who have solved this who can give me some feedback.

the following code is my output from terminal in linux manjaro, and when i try to intall the ecapture via package install pip, i get this following error.

```
$ pip install numpy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.20.3)

$ pip install pep517
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pep517 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.10.0)

 
$ pip3 install ecapture     
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ecapture
  Using cached ecapture-0.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting scikit-image==0.14.2
  Using cached scikit-image-0.14.2.tar.gz (27.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.5.2.52-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (51.0 MB)
Collecting PyWavelets>=0.4.0
  Using cached PyWavelets-1.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting dask[array]>=1.0.0
  Using cached dask-2021.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (1.16.0)
Collecting matplotlib>=2.0.0
  Using cached matplotlib-3.4.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
Collecting networkx>=1.8
  Using cached networkx-2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (8.2.0)
Collecting cloudpickle>=0.2.1
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (1.6.3)
Collecting toolz>=0.8.2
  Using cached toolz-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[array]>=1.0.0->scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (5.4.1)
Collecting partd>=0.3.10
  Using cached partd-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting fsspec>=0.6.0
  Using cached fsspec-2021.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from dask[array]>=1.0.0->scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=2.0.0->scikit-image==0.14.2->ecapture) (2.4.7)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting decorator<5,>=4.3
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting locket
  Using cached locket-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-image
  Building wheel for scikit-image (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python /home/yaserf/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpsb3j2vlm                                      
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_b4bnp4h/scikit-image_929d227b9ff34c41ae8ff9e30520c25c                                                                                                        
  Complete output (866 lines):                                                                                                                                                             
  Partial import of skimage during the build process.                                                                                                                                      
  running bdist_wheel                                                                                                                                                                      
  running build                                                                                                                                                                            
  running config_cc                                                                                                                                                                        
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options                                                                                                      
  running config_fc                                                                                                                                                                        
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options                                                                                                     
  running build_src                                                                                                                                                                        
  build_src                                                                                                                                                                                
 
  ########### EXT COMPILER OPTIMIZATION ###########
  Platform      :
    Architecture: x64
    Compiler    : gcc
  
  CPU baseline  :
    Requested   : 'min'
    Enabled     : SSE SSE2 SSE3
    Flags       : -msse -msse2 -msse3
    Extra checks: none
  
  CPU dispatch  :
    Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'
    Enabled     : SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42 AVX F16C FMA3 AVX2 AVX512F AVX512CD AVX512_KNL AVX512_KNM AVX512_SKX AVX512_CLX AVX512_CNL AVX512_ICL
    Generated   : none
  CCompilerOpt._cache_write[796] : write cache to path -> /tmp/pip-install-_b4bnp4h/scikit-image_929d227b9ff34c41ae8ff9e30520c25c/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/ccompiler_opt_cache_ext.py
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the below first

```
pip install numpy
pip install pep517
```